# Lucene query building in neo4jrestclient?

Tags: python, rest, neo4j, lucene

I'm trying to follow these docs:
http://readthedocs.org/docs/neo4j-rest-client/en/latest/indices.html
This works fine

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase, Q
db = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
userIndex = db.nodes.indexes.get("index2")
print userIndex.query('username', "*")[:]
```

and according to the docs, this should also work, but doesn't.

```
print userIndex.query(Q('username', "*"))[:]
```

I upgraded to the latest version in the pip repository. Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you post the raw REST call going over the wire for reference, so I can take a look?

Comment: sure. How do I capture the REST request?

Comment: @user890477 you can use a tool like Wireshark, or you can use pdb to trace the calls in neo4jrestclient until the HTTP requests are constructed, and show us those.

Comment: @PeterNeubauer it's almost certainly neo4j-rest-client or lucene-querybuilder.

Comment: Another option is to enable the [`DEBUG` mode](http://readthedocs.org/docs/neo4j-rest-client/en/latest/info.html#options).

Comment: @versae I hadn't seen that, cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is an issue on [neo4j-rest-client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4jrestclient/) than the [lucene-querybuilder](https://github.com/scholrly/lucene-querybuilder). Anyway, you can try using the argument `wildcard` like:

```
print userIndex.query(Q('username', "*", wildcard=True))[:]
```

And tell me if it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is/was a bug, which I filed here:
https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/issues/67